# WireGuard does not work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, client, wireguard

I have generated configuration for wireguard where I manualy added to `[Interface] PostUp` and `PostDown` routes, for my interfaces.

Here is my censored configuration which I am running via `wg-quick up file.conf`
I am also having routes showing via my `ip ro` and also `wg-status show` is showting routes exists and some traffic is outcoming.

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = privatekey=
Address = my-vpn-ip,my-vpn-ip6
PostUp = ip route add ip-address/32 dev ens160;ip route add ip-address/32 dev ens160;ip route add ip-address/32 dev ens160;ip route addip-address/32 dev ens160;
PostDown = ip route del ip-address/32 dev ens160;ip route del ip-address/32 dev ens160;ip route del ip-address/32 dev ens160;ip route del ip-address/32 dev ens160;
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey1=
Endpoint = end-point-ip1:7200
AllowedIPs = ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey2=
Endpoint = end-point-ip2:7200
AllowedIPs = ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey3=
Endpoint = end-point-ip3:7200
AllowedIPs = ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey4=
Endpoint = end-point-ip4:7200
AllowedIPs = ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32,ip-address/32
```

I can access internet, but can't access internal servers, WireGuard works fine on my windows machine but on Ubuntu it does not. `Openresolve` package is installed.

I configured in `/etc/sysctl.conf` `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and `net.ipv6.ip_forward = 1`

Comment: I didn't read all your question, but it works perfectly on 18.04...Did something change?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20, there is a 20.04 and a 20.10

Comment: edited my question .. sorry for version mystification.

Comment: @David not sure if it is general bug, or some local bug, but I just have clean installation which is weird it does not work.

Comment: I use WireGuard on 20.04 in GCP with no problems. Maybe you have a firewall configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bug in WG which was not routing packets propertly.

My collegue from L3 department wrote hot fix, this issue was reported as bug.

```
PostUp = MYDEFROUTE=`ip ro sh | grep default | awk '{print $3}'| head -n1`; for peer in ip.addresses.here; do ip ro add $peer/32 via $MYDEFROUTE; done
PostDown = for peer in ip.addresses; do ip ro del $peer/32; done
```